# passing argument as promise to other function that uses double brace

Tags: r, dplyr, promise, curly-braces

I am familiar with the **embrace** [dplyr syntax](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) which allows to dynamically pass an unquoted variable name as argument to a function. For example, after defining

```
library(dplyr)
pull_column <- function(tb, colname) {
    tb %>% 
        pull({{colname}})
}
```

It is possible to pull for example the `name` column from the `starwars` tibble by running

```
starwars %>% pull_column(name)
```

My aim is to create another function which also takes a `colname` argument and then uses the supplied value to forward as an argument to the `pull_column()` function. For example, this function first filters by eye color and then calls `pull_column()`:

```
pull_column_for_eyecolor <- function(tb, colname, eyecolor){
    tb %>% 
        filter(eye_color == eyecolor) %>% 
        pull_column(colname)
}
```

yet when I call this function to get the names of the yellow-eyed characters via

```
starwars %>% pull_column_for_eyecolor(name, "yellow")
```

I get

> Error: object 'name' not found

Is there a way to supply an unquoted value to the `colname` argument for both the `pull_column()` and `pull_column_for_eyecolor()` functions without running into an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your `pull_column_for_eyecolor` function as

```
pull_column_for_eyecolor <- function(tb, colname, eyecolor){
  qColName <- enquo(colname)
  tb %>% 
    filter(eye_color == eyecolor) %>% 
    pull_column(!! qColName)
}
```

so that

```
starwars %>% pull_column_for_eyecolor(name, "yellow")
 [1] "C-3PO"             "Darth Vader"       "Palpatine"         "Watto"             "Darth Maul"        "Dud Bolt"          "Ki-Adi-Mundi"      "Yarael Poof"       "Poggle the Lesser"
[10] "Zam Wesell"        "Dexter Jettster"
```

See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for details.  It's a classic non-standard evaluation issue.

Comment: This works perfect for my case. The source you mention does not discuss `enquo` and the old tidyeval website https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/ (that did discuss it) says it has been superseded. So I am not sure what's the authoritative source to go to. Do you have a suggestion?